# PHP Create File on Network Share

Tags: php, file, networking, directory, share

I can read files using PHP from a network share, but how can I create a file and folder on a network share?

Comment: If you can read files, writing is technically the same. Do you have permissions to write to the share?

Answer (score 5):

Same way you would a local file.

```
$fp = fopen("\\\\server\\share\\folder\\file.txt","w");
```

You must have permission to create/write, also.

Comment: I don't think it works without the slashes.  Because `'\\'` is interpreted as the string: `\`...  Either way, the extra escaping can't hurt...